# Delete multiple contacts

Tags: telegram

How do I delete multiple telegram contacts / Refresh contacts to reflect only my current address book? My telegram has way too many old contacts that I deleted from phones years ago. How do I delete this contacts or /and refresh telegram contacts to reflect my current contact address book?

Comment: Unless you plan on doing this programmatically, I think you may have asked on the wrong SE website. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) may be a better fit.

Comment: Any answer is welcomed @Hoi_A

Answer (score 7):

Another way you could refresh your contacts is:
Telegram-Settings-Privacy and Security-Delete synced contacts. This will refresh all your telegram contacts.
By the way I have an Android phone, I don't know if it is different on another device

Answer (score 6):

You can try these steps for deleting multiple contacts on Telegram (Could only do this via Telegram web):

- Go to [Telegram Web](https://web.telegram.org)
- Login with your details
- Click on the Menu (Three strokes on the top left corner)
- Click on Contacts
- Click on Edit
- Select multiple contacts
- Delete

See [link](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-delete-multiple-contacts-on-Telegram) for source.

Comment: Nice solution, it seems this is the only way to delete multiple contacts at the same time.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this only works in the legacy version of the web client, which can be accessed with [this link](https://web.telegram.org/?legacy=1)